# Nightmare not resolving Adidas Site

Tags: javascript, electron, nightmare

I'm trying out NightmareJS for a few automations I'd like to accomplish. An issue I've encountered though is that Nightmare/Electron cannot resolve the adidas website, however it can resolve and visit any other web page.

[This is what it looks like when it trys to visit adidas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMfrN.png)

Does anybody know how to fix this? Every other site works perfectly. Here's how I'm trying to connect.

```
const Nightmare = require("nightmare");
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

nightmare
    .goto('https://adidas.com')
    .wait('#r1-0 a.result__a')
    .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#r1-0 a.result__a').href)
    .end()
    .then(console.log)
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Search failed:', error);
    });
```

Comment: are you missing the www? - https://www.adidas.com?  I get page cannot be found on https://adidas.com/

Comment: Usually a good idea to try it in the browser...

Comment: @Mark_M Works perfectly in the browser.

Comment: @ChrisNevill I'm trying it and it works perfectly in the browser for me.

Comment: Not working in the browser for me with `https` just hangs.

Comment: `https` does not work in the browser. Their landing page is not `https`

Answer (score 0):

The URL you should be using is : `http://www.adidas.com/us/`

Answer (score 0):

The url worked for me was `http://www.global.adidas.com/` and `http://www.adidas.com/us/`, 
the `https` version did not work for me on the browser, It is down for other tools too.

[image]

You can try to use the following switch when launching nightmare,

```
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  switches: {
    'ignore-certificate-errors': true
  }
});
```

and also you can use `DEBUG=* node app.js` to find out more about the problem.